# Set Jenkins environment variable in the post build step

Tags: jenkins

I thought this should be simple, but apparently it is not... or I am trying to do it the wrong way :)

I am using the Mattermost plugin for sending chat notifications at the end of a job run. This works great.

Now I would like to add an URL to the notification. A part of this URL is generated during the job run in the post build step. My approach was to export the dynamically generated part into an environment variable in the post build step and than pass it to the Mattermost plugins. The plugin can work with ${}-variables. Nonetheless the passed variable is empty/not accessible, although it was set correctly during the script execution.

So the question is: how can I set an environment variable in a post build script execution, so that it is available to other steps/plugin?

I did look into the [EnInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) but it works only in the build step, not the post build.

#### Edit

The post build script is a simple bash script, which runs a `curl` command and saves its output in a variable `POST_RESULT`. I extract a substring in the form of "BLA-123" from this result . This is what is than saved into `EXECUTION_TAG` and exported:

`export EXECUTION_TAG=$(echo $POST_RESULT | grep -oP "(BLA-\d+)")`

The `EXECUTON_TAG` is what I want to add to the URL displayed in the Mattermost notification like this:

`Execution URL: http://some.random.link/execution/${EXECUTION_TAG}`

Comment: This is fairly easy to accomplish. You are likely running into scoping issues, or setting a groovy variable, not an environment variable. Post some code and it will be easier to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution I came up with:

Based on the suggestions from *prudviraj* I created another job (job B), that handles just the Mettermost notifications. The actual job (job A) runs all the build steps saving all needed information as environment variables in a file. At the end job A triggers job B passing the file with variables. Job B uses the variables to build the notification text and send it to Mattermost.

One a bit tricky thing was to also pass the status of the job A (SUCCESS or FAILURE), so that the notification created in job B gets the right colour (green or red) based on this. After trying out few solutions with Groovy I settled with using the Conditional step in the build phase of job A. This one sets another environment variable BULID_STATUS based on the job status. This variable is than passed to job B where a simple bash if-block makes the job either fail or succeed:

```
if [ "$BUILD_STATUS" != 'SUCCESS' ]
    then 
        exit 1
fi
```

This is ok, as all I want to know is whether the job failed or not. Other statuses are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Not sure if you would be able to resolve this using jenkins plugins.

Have couple of ways by which you can send job notifications :

1. Use incoming web hooks to send notification to mattermost channels, instead of using plugins.
2. Created a child job ( can be common for all jobs ) you can call that job as notify_matter_most. Trigger this job as a child job to the above job and make sure parent job details are passed onto child job which in turn use those details and send notification to mattermost using mattermost plugin